# AWS error when creating an SNS Topic Subscription when RawMessageDelivery set to false

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I want to create a subscription for a Lambda function endpoint, which does not support Raw Message Delivery, so I send the attribute 'RawDelivery'='false' as illustrated in the below code:

```
sns_client = boto3.client('sns', region_name='us-east-2')
topic_arn = 'arn:aws:sns:us-east-2:myacct:my-topic'
protocol = 'lambda'
endpoint = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:myacct:function:my-lambda-function'
attribs = dict()
attribs['RawMessageDelivery'] = 'false'
sns_client.subscribe(TopicArn=topic_arn, Protocol=protocol, Endpoint=endpoint,
                     Attributes=attribs)
```

However, AWS responds with this error:

```
Invalid parameter: Attributes Reason: Delivery protocol [lambda] does not support raw message delivery.
```

According to the AWS Boto3 docs:

> When set to true ,[RawMessageDelivery] enables raw message delivery to Amazon SQS or HTTP/S endpoints.

I'm setting it to 'false', not 'true', so why does AWS think I'm trying to enable raw message delivery?

Answer (score 1):

```
attribs['RawMessageDelivery'] = 'false'
```

You're setting the attribute to `'false'` instead of `False`.  `'false'`, a string, is a truthy value

```
% python <<<"print('truthy' if 'false' else 'not truthy')"                                                                   
truthy
```

Probably you don't need to set the attribute at all.  From the text I would guess `False` is the default.

Comment: Makes sense from a python perspective, but the Boto3 API requires the value to be a string, not a boolean . See subscribe()  docs:  https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sns.html#SNS.Client.subscribe

Comment: just omit the attribute and you should be fine.  have you tried?

Comment: Leaving out attribute RawMessageDelivery does work by defaulting to false.  But it's surprising behavior that AWS doesn't also allow setting that attribute with value to 'false' to indicate no raw message delivery.  Anyway if you want to add a new answer or rework your answer above to indicate omitting the attribute as a workaround, I'll accept it.

Comment: Well, the docs say "string".  Being untyped language we'd have to look at the  botocore code to see how that was implemented.  It does seem strange given the documentation that `false` would be equivalent to `true`.